# scala code works on spark-shell but not in spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following is the main scala code

```
1.val conf=new SparkConf()
2.conf.setMaster("spark://master:7077")
3.conf.setAppName("Commnity Detective")
4.val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
5.val rdd=sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/lvcy/test/ungraph/test.txt")
6.val maprdd=rdd.map(line =>{val p=line.split("\\s+");(p(0),p(1))}) union rdd.map( line =>{val p=line.split("\\s+");(p(1),p(0))})
7.val reducerdd=maprdd.reduceByKey((a,b)=>a+"\t"+b)
8.val reduceArray=reducerdd.collect()
9.val reducemap=reduceArray.toMap
```

Problem statement:

1. copy the code(line:5-9) running on spark-shell, the result is right
2. if put the code to the Eclipse and generate jar packages,then use "spark-submit" to submit the job, there has next error("Main:scala:21" is the top line:9, that is to say the method toMap Error,**WHY?**):

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
   at net.lvcy.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:21)
   at net.lvcy.main.Main.main(Main.scala)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Scala version mismatch. You should make sure that the Scala version used to generate your jar is the same as the Scala version of your Spark cluster binaries, e.g. `2.10`.

Comment: My local scala version is 2.11.7 and the version of spark cluster is 2.11.7 too

Comment: Is `2.11.7` also the version you've defined in your build script?

Comment: Yes exactly. And also make sure that all the Spark dependencies in your pom are build using Scala `2.11`. They have the respective suffix `_2.11`.

Comment: the next is my pom.xml,I do not kown how to modify it 

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

Comment: the key is the method "toMap" is Error

Comment: The problem is still not resolved. By rights `RDD[(string, string)]` convert into `Array[(String, String)]` and `Array[(String, String)]` convert into Map[(String, String)] is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Prebuild Spark distribution is compiled with Scala 2.10, so ensure that you're running your spark cluster under scala 2.10.